# A bit stuck in a modelling exercise

Tags: uml, associations, modeling, class-diagram

I'm a bit stuck in a modelling exercise.  I'm supposed to have two classes, `Employee` and `Manager`.  A manager is assigned to an employee and we have to know since when it's been assigned.  An employee can have a history of several past managers and the current manager is the one with the most recent date. I currently have something like this:

[image: Idea]

but it doesn't feel right.  Any ideas or hints on how to do it?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it doesn't feel right?  Could you explain what expenseManager's starting date is meant for ? Could you confirm that employees that leave the company are immediately deleted (hence `1..*`)? Could you explain how you take into account an employee who leaves the company and is hired again:  do you need his/her history as well?

Answer (score -1):

Physical deletions should be avoided; it is better to prefer logical deletions with a date or a boolean. In your case, the diagram is correct but information is indeed missing: cannot an employee exist, for a period, without a manager? The easiest: replace IsCurrentManager by endingDate and when the date is null, it is the current manager. In the db, the primary key will be id Employee + id Manager + startingDate